# Write a text file with Cedilla Delimer(Ç) - non keyboard printable character

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a program where I am writing a Pipe Delimited file using PySpark. I want to write the file using Ç - cedilla as the delimiter.

sample code

```py
separator = '|'
concat_udf1 = F.udf(lambda cols: "".join([x+separator if x is not None else "separator" for x in cols]), StringType())
```

Current dataframe output

```
7|2020-03-31|xyz
7|2020-03-31|abc
```

New dataframe output

```
7Ç2020-03-31Çxyz
7Ç2020-03-31Çabc
```

If I am changing the separator to Ç - cedilla I get below error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any help would be appreciated - TIA

Comment: What throws this error? It's a classic case of improper encoding usage (and that's what the error is telling you as well).

Answer (score 0):

This command on the terminal will work as intented:

```
< cedilla-dataframe-txt tr '\u00c7' '|'
```

Or instead of `'\u00c7'` can paste the cedilla character.